# Create collection with default document mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to create collection named "Admins" in my mongodb. Problem is that new admins can be added only by already existing admin but on initial state I don't have any admins.

What is most convienient way to create default admin when creating new collection? My schema is

```
const adminSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 128
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

Comment: You can use default script which can add record if not exist  in index/app file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a script, say seed.js, to safely insert as many users as required.

```
            //seed.js
            var Admin = require('../path/to/admin.js');

            // you can refer any other flow to get count or number of record
            Admin.countDocuments({}, function( err, count){

                console.log( "Number of users:", count );

                // decide ur other logic

                // if count is 0 or less
                if(count <= 0) {

                    var user = {
                        name: "Admin User",
                        email: "admin@gmail.com",
                        password: "admin"
                    }

                    Admin.create(user, function(e) {
                        if (e) {
                            throw e;
                        }
                    });
                }

            })
```

With latest approach you can may use following way

```
    try {


            // you can refer here any other method to get count or number of record
            let count = await Admin.countDocuments({});

            if(count <= 0) {
                var user = {
                    name: "Admin User",
                    email: "admin@gmail.com",
                    password: "admin"
                }
                const admin = new Admin(user);
                await admin.save()
            }

        } catch (err) {

            console.log(err);
        }
```

Require `seed.js` in your `server.js or app.js` script right after the connection to mongodb is made. Comment or remove this line when you are done seeding.

```
require('../path/to/seed');
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: shoudn't `Admin.create` from your snippet be something like `const admin = new Admin(user) await admin.save()`? I want to save to mongodb with mongooose

Comment: `count` and `user` could be constant also it should be in async function :D but i get it no worries, thanks

Comment: Also `count` method is deprecated, should use `countDocuments`